# How do I keep my website content from moving during zoom?

Tags: css, web, html

I couldn't think of the right wording for this question, but here is my problem:

When users hit Ctrl+Plus to zoom in on my page, content seems to push each other around.
For example, I have a navigation div floating on its own on the top left corner of the page.

Then there is main content text that is centered in the page.  When the user zooms in, the centered content quickly moves left towards the navigation and eventually starts wrapping around it and it looks awful.

Is there a high-level way that you can describe to me how to structure my page so that zooming keeps things stable and 'just zooms in' without distorting the original positioning?

Comment: Which browser is this behavior happening in?

Comment: Maybe structuring your website with tables may solve your problem.

Comment: Which page? How are you positioning your elements? Which browser, which type of zoom?

Comment: This is in any browser.  My main elements are positioned within divs that float left.  Tables are not meant for website layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link from "A List Apart"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/) covers some font sizing and fluid web development. It should give you some good direction of how to structure your page to adapt to changes in font sizes. You may also want to look into [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) because they allow you to apply styles based on certain characteristics of the browser or device.

Answer (score 0):

## How to keep code in center on zooming?

## Center the code on zooming?

**ANSWER:**
 
 ***< div id="wrapper"> Place this div tag outside the code   < /div>***

```
   #wrapper
   {
   background-color: #F00;
   width: 400px;//This width can be anything according to your need
   margin-right: auto;//Note margin-right and left are allocated automatically
   margin-left: auto;
   }
```

**Another Way**

```
   #wrapper
   {
   background-color: #F00;
   width: 400px;
   position:relative;
   }
```